# errors extruding shapes with three.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js

I'm just getting started with three.js, and having some issues extruding some 2d shapes.

I have a GeoJSON file containing all the counties in the US.  I'm using d3.js and a `d3.geo.albersUSa()` projection to convert each latitude/longitude into a list of X/Y coordinates to make a `THREE.Shape` that I'm then extruding and drawing.  This seems to work OK for most counties.

The issue I'm seeing is that some subset of counties either fail to extrude or extrude incorrectly with the following sequences of warnings:

```
Warning, unable to triangulate polygon!
Duplicate point 653.4789181355854:204.0166729191409
Either infinite or no solutions!
Its finite solutions.
Either infinite or no solutions!
Too bad, no solutions.
```

I'm not sure I understand exactly what the issue is -- as far as I can tell, there's nothing special about these particular shapes.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this an issue with the extrusion code in three.js?

---

For example here are some missing counties:

Also notice the triangular 'hourglass' missing pieces in Texas:  these look like some counties which were only half rendered (they ended up as triangles instead of rectangles or squares?)

[image: Example output]
[Larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLkcB.png)

Apologies for the huge code dump, I tried to pare it down as much as possible.

#### setup:

```
/* initialize the scene, camera, light, and background plane */
var Map = function(params) {
  this.width     = params.width;
  this.height    = params.height;
  this.container = params.target || document.body;

  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
  this.renderer.setClearColorHex(0x303030, 1.0);

  this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

  this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, this.width / this.height,
                                            1, 10000);
  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  this.scene.add(this.camera);

  this.camera.position.z = 550;
  this.camera.position.x = 0;
  this.camera.position.y = 550;

  this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position);

  this.projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1000)
    .translate([250, 0]);


 var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
 pointLight.position.x = 800;
 pointLight.position.y = 800;
 pointLight.position.z = 800;

  var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000, 10, 10),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff})
  );

  plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;

  this.scene.add(pointLight);
  this.scene.add(plane);
```

};

#### rendering:

```
/* given a GeoJSON Feature, return a list of Vector2s
 * describing where to draw the feature, using the provided projection. */
function path(proj, feature) {
  if (feature.geometry.type == 'Polygon') {
    return polygonPath(proj, feature.geometry.coordinates);
  } else if (feature.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon') {
    return multiPolygonPath(proj, feature.geometry.coordinates);
  }
}

/* a GeoJSON Polygon is a set of 'rings'.  The first ring is the shape of the polygon.
 * each subsequent ring is a hole inside that polygon. */
function polygonPath(proj, rings) {
  var list = [];
  var cur  = [];

  $.each(rings, function(i, ring) {
    cur = [];

    $.each(ring, function(i, coord) {
      var pts = proj(coord);
      cur.push(new THREE.Vector2(pts[0], pts[1]));
    });

    list.push(cur);
  });

  return list;
}

/* a GeoJSON MultiPolgyon is just a series of Polygons. */
function multiPolygonPath(proj, polys) {
  var list = [];
  $.each(polys, function(i, poly) {
    list.push(polygonPath(proj, poly));
  });
  return list;
}

/* for each feature, find it's X/Y Path, create shape(s) with the required holes,
 * and extrude the shape */
function renderFeatures(proj, features, scene, isState) {
  var color = 0x33ccff;

  $.each(features, function(i, feature) {
    var polygons = path(proj, feature);
    if (feature.geometry.type != 'MultiPolygon') {
      polygons = [polygons];
    }

    $.each(polygons, function(i, poly) {
      var shape = new THREE.Shape(poly[0]);

      if (poly.length > 1) {
        shape.holes = poly.slice(1).map(function(item) { return new THREE.Shape(item); });
      }

      var geom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, { amount: 20, bevelEnabled: false });
      var c = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color}) );

      c.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
      c.translateX(-290);
      c.translateZ(50);
      c.translateY(5);

      scene.add(c);
    });
  });
}

Map.prototype.renderCounties = function() {
  $.getJSON('/data/us-counties.json', function(json) {
    renderFeatures(this.projection, json.features, this.scene, false);
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to identify one county for each error message and produce a simple example. If you find no errors in your data for those counties, and you believe it should work, then you can submit that example to the three.js issues board in the form of a bug report.

Comment: Can you share your json? I wanted to test it with another triangulation library...

Comment: Sure, you can find the county data here: https://github.com/ledbettj/us-map/tree/threejs/public/data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the points of the polygon are in the wrong order.

Comment: Actually it turns out that there were some back-to-back duplicated points (per the error message) -- checking for this and throwing them away seems to have resolved most if not all of the holes.  I'm going to go ahead and give it to you since you led me to the right answer :).